# How to use a jquery HEAD request to obtain just metadata (response headers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, metadata

So, I've just read online about a fairly specialized HTTP method known as HEAD, which is basically supposed to only send metadata, without sending the actual document body. It seems that jQuery supports this, but when I attempted to create it for real, the body was still sent along with the headers. When I checked in the console, Chrome told me that a head request was actually sent. Huh?
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = 'UTF-8'/>
<title>Headers</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" 
src="2-jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" 
src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // not exactly necessary for head requests
// to be used for other ajax request types
//..is this interfering?

function reloader() { 
$.ajax({ type: 'HEAD', url: "chatbox.txt" })

.done(function(data, status, xmlhttp) { 
console.log(xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified')); })

.fail(function() { alert("error!"); })

.always( function() {} ); } // end reloader

var matrix = setInterval(reloader,3000);
$('#stop').click(function() { clearInterval(matrix); alert('stopped!');
}); // end click

}); // end $(document).ready()

</script>
<button id = 'stop'>Stop</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine, except for the body being sent as well. What's the problem exactly? Am I accidentally sending the body along with the request? If so, where in the code is this? 
P.S. I know I can do this with PHP, but I'm interested in js/jQ.
Thanks!

Comment: isn't this the responsibility of the server?

Comment: Same way you use any get requmest, just use `$.ajax({ type: "HEAD", ...})`.

Comment: The body is being sent as well. That's the point of the question...

Comment: You should return only headers.

Comment: At what point in the code am I returning something other than headers? That would be useful.

Comment: What have you on server side ?